# Make validation in Rust simple

Tags: rust

I have input with 2 variables (x and y). I need to check that they are not Null and both of them don't contain "?". I achieved it with my code, but for me it seems not super optimized. Is it possible (for sure it is, but I don't know how) to improve it?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum TestError {
    ContainsQuestionMark,
}

pub type TestResult = Result<bool, TestError>;

fn main() {
    let x = Some(String::from("x"));
    let y = Some(String::from("y"));

    if x.is_some() && y.is_some() {
        let x = x.clone().unwrap();
        let y = y.clone().unwrap();
        if validate(&x, &y).is_ok() {
            out(&x, &y);
        }
    } else {
        println!("x and y are Null");
    }
}

fn validate(x: &String, y: &String) -> TestResult {
    if x.contains("?") || y.contains("?") {
        println!("x or y contains ?");
        return Err(TestError::ContainsQuestionMark);
    }
    Ok(true)
}

fn out(x: &String, y: &String) {
    println!("These are x = {x}, y = {y}");
    std::process::exit(0);
}
```

Comment: If this is working code, ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference &String, &Vec, or &Box as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-string-vec-or-box-as-a-function)

Comment: Thanks for Code review suggestion. I did not know about this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [if-let](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/if_let.html) to both check and unwrap options at the same time.

```
if let Some(x) = &x {
    if let Some(y) = &y {
        if validate(x, y).is_ok() {
            out(x, y);
        }
    } else {
        println!("y is None");
    }
} else {
    println!("x is None");
}
```

You could get fancy and match both at the same time by stuffing `&x` and `&y` into a tuple.

```
if let (Some(x), Some(y)) = (&x, &y) {
    if validate(x, y).is_ok() {
        out(x, y);
    }
} else {
    println!("x or y is None");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4e9fcf192d120b0a359ab56cf90ad6c8)

---

By the way, it's [better to take function parameters as `&str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html#string-slices-as-parameters) rather than `&String`. A `&str` can accept not only `String` references, but also static strings and string slices that aren't stored in mutable `String` buffers. There's no ergonomic cost since `&String` references automatically convert into `&str`.

```
fn validate(x: &str, y: &str) -> TestResult {
    ...
}

fn out(x: &str, y: &str) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: [The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html#string-slices-as-parameters) has a good chapter on `&str` vs. `&String` as a function parameter.

Also, borrowing in the `if let` statement is also a neat trick I didn't know of!